# How to filter the available fields in Netsuite using RESTlet?

Tags: netsuite

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1612
        [phone] => 9638527410
        [email] => sample@gmail.com
        [entityid] => dummy entity
        ........
        [recordtype] => contact
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1812
        [email] => sample0@gmail.com
        [entityid] => dummy entity0
        ........
        [recordtype] => contact
    )
    .........
    .........
```

I got the result of all contacts like above. But now I want get only who is having Phone no. I tried

filters[0] = new nlobjSearchFilter('phone', null, 'noneof', '@NONE@');.

No success. What filter should use to get the my desired result?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below should work using nlobjSearchFilter

```
nlapiSearchRecord('contact', null, 
     new nlobjSearchFilter('phone', null, 'isnotempty'));
```

If you are looking for filter expression:

```
nlapiSearchRecord('contact', null, ['phone', 'isnotempty', ''])
```

Comment: The `noneof` and `anyof` search operators are only for List/Record (Select) fields in NetSuite. `phone` is a text field, so you need to use the text operators like `isnotempty` as @prasun indicated. Check out the NS Help page titled "Search Operators" to see a list of all possible operators and which types of fields they can be applied to.

Comment: Its working fine.Thank u soooooooooo much prasun and egrubaugh.